# Hive issues in HDinsights

Tags: azure, hive, azure-hdinsight

When I run my hive queries in Azure HDInsights cluster I get the following error message:

> ERROR exec.DDLTask: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   MetaException(message:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI:).

I'm not sure what is the reason for this error. Can anyone explain what does this error means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with the relative path or an absolute path.

Could you please provide the path as mentioned below:

```
STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'wasb://"spark-container-name"@"storage-account-name".blob.core.windows.net/financedata/nikkei_stock_average_daily_en.csv';
```

For more details, refer “[Address files in Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage#address-files-in-azure-storage)”.

Hope this helps.